# Combining two windows in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

**How can you combine two windows in Screen?**

I have two windows such that I can move between them by `^A p` or `^A n` in Screen.

I would like to combine two windows which have the numbers 1 and 3.

Comment: What does "combine two windows" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the current view with ^A S (or ^A | for vert) then switch to the new view with ^A ^I.  The ^A ^N will iterate over available windows.  This way you can see both windows in one view.

Not sure what the definition of 'combine' is, but this is one way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! - I did not know the `^A |`.

Comment: **What is this `^l` in this `^A ^l`?** I unsuccessfully press small `L` as `l`.

Comment: Ahh, it's actually an uppercase i.

Comment: The command gives me `This window is already logged in.` - **Do you mean to press `CTRL-a SHIFT-i` or `CTRL-a CTRL-SHIFT-i`?** - I ran both unsuccessfully.

Comment: ^a ^i will switch focus to another pane inside of screen.  Another handy shortcut is ^a ? which shows a digest of available commands.